# Regex to find spaces not working

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to only let the user input characters from the alphabet, excluding spaces too. I'm using one regex expression to find the letters (r'[a-zA-Z]+') and another to find the spaces ('\s+') or (' +') and then using a while statement to check it:

```
# regex rules
alphabet_regex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
space_regex = re.compile('\s+')

key = str(input("1) Insert your keyword generate the number: "))

while not alphabet_regex.match(key) and not space_regex.match(key):
    error(keywordError)
    key = str(input("1) Insert your keyword to generate the number: "))
```

The letter finder works perfectly but the spaces don't. You can put one wherever you want and it will ignore it.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: `match` means *starting from the first character*, you probably want `.search(..)` instead.

Comment: You're doing it the hard way. You should put the negatives into a single regex.`while re.search(r'(?i)[^a-z\s]',key):` Every thing inside a negative class is anded together, so not a-z _and_ not \s

Comment: thanks Willem i did't notice that!

Comment: The way your logic is set up (after switching to `search`) both alphabetic characters and spaces will be allowed. Is that what you want? Because it's a whitelist, if you only want to allow alphabetic characters, then that's all you need to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` matches from the start i.e. it is same as using `re.search(r'^...')`. So, in your alphabetic match, it is matching from the start and presumably you're getting the desired result. In your whitespace case, if the input string does not have whitespace at start, it won't match.

So, you can use `re.search` with Regex:

```
space_regex = re.compile('\s')
```

If you insist on using `re.match`:

```
space_regex = re.compile('.*\s')
```

---

Also note that, here matching a single whitespace would do, you don't need to match one or more using the `+` quantifier.

---

**Edit:**

Seeing at your plan, you could achive the same with a much simpler Regex -- check only for alphabetics with proper anchoring of start and end:

```
^[A-Za-z]+$
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reminding me match and search, but after trying ('\s') it still doesn't work. Maybe i'm still missing something?

Comment: @b0ss192301 I don't see why it should not be working. See if you have all the logic sorted out. If in doubt, show me some examples please.

Comment: you can see it yourself here https://repl.it/@glow8/LiveKindSambar when you input "test" or "t e s t" and both will work

Comment: @b0ss192301 You have a logical error, you need `while not alphabet_regex.search(key) or space_regex.search(key):`